# Using SpecFlow to test a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, specflow

In order to add SpecFlow tests to a series of WPF applications I'm currently trying to combine SpecFlow with a very simple WPF test application in VS.NET 2012.

I'm following the [steps outlined in SpecFlow's getting-started](http://www.specflow.org/getting-started/), with the distinction that I have a solution containing two projects (the WPF one along side the SpecFlow one).

I've got a single scenario and step definitions for its steps. <del>Unfortunately no tests are listed in the test explorer and choosing "Run SpecFlow Scenarios" (as per step 6 in the [getting started](http://www.specflow.org/getting-started/)) nothing happens.</del> After discovering that on VS.NET 2012 an NUnit test adapter is required I can get the tests to run. Unfortunately I'm now stumped at opening the window-under-test:

```
namespace SpecOverflow
{
    [Binding]
    public class StepDefinitions
    {
        static private BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        private MainWindow win;

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void CreateWindow()
        {
            // Need to run this in a separate thread because we get "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." errors otherwise
            _bw.DoWork += (_,__) => { win = new MainWindow(); };
            _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            while (_bw.IsBusy)
                ;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

This however doesn't seem to create a window (I get a NullReferenceException in the first build step that uses it).

I should add that I've got more than 0 experience with VS.NET but only barely (probably 
less than 100 hours in 2 years, most C# experience I've got is with Mono). I'm trying to do this project because I've got some time right now and a colleague asked me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently creating the window in a thread of its own with a so-called "STA" "ApartmentState" does it:

```
var winThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    win = new MainWindow();
    win.Closed += (sender, e) => win.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});

winThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
winThread.Start();
```